# Rear camber alignment off, outside tire wear

Tags: tires, alignment

Hoping to get some help from unbiased sources who aren't trying to sell me parts.[image: Alignment sheet here]

The car is a 2014 Honda Accord LX. It has no adjustable camber in the rear without aftermarket parts. I've noticed additional wear on the outside of my tires. It seems that the Accords are leaving the factory with negative camber pretty regularly, but I am unsure what is considered safe for tire wear considering the lack of adjustability. I saw one person who did end up buying a camber adjustment kit ended up removing it because the bushings were too soft.

Comment: By "off" - how much "off" ? If those tiny figures are the acceptable range then I would assume that the right rear has hit the kerb at some point or a bush in the suspension has failed or is failing... Have all the other bushes been checked **thoroughly** ? Are any of the suspension arms bent or have they been used to jack the car up at some point - that is sufficient to cause damage and incorrect values...

Comment: For starters, that's negative camber, so I'd expect the tires to be wearing on the *inside* of the tires (and it doesn't happen if you hit the curb, from the side anyway). Secondly, what do you mean you're "unsure what is considered safe for tire wear"? What is this question asking? Clearly if you look at the sheet, your rear camber is slightly to somewhat out of the acceptable ranges for your car. If you leave it like that, then expect to replace tires a little more often than usual.

Comment: @SolarMike - Car only has 25k miles, usually driven only in town. No real collisions. I did drive into a cement stub, but it only impacted the body panel as it was a scrape rather than a bump.

I have no clue how to check the bushes or suspension arms. I'm guessing I would need a lift for that? Or to get the car up on 4 jack stands?I've only ever lifted the car by the jack points, and I am hoping the dealership has only used a lift.

Comment: @Kitsunemimi The reason why I'm asking is that it seems like Hondas are coming from the factory with out of alignment camber quite often. Without rear camber adjustment arms, getting it in alignment is a crapshoot with hoping the replacement parts get it back in alignment = $$$. I'm wondering how much loss of tire life I'd see with this alignment since my tires are more likely to dry rot before I run out of tread life with ~7-8k miles a year. I don't know why the tire wear is on the outside more than the inside, maybe the front alignment is the cause? My driver left side tire has the most wear

Comment: Honda are not the only ones who have no adjustment - the Jaguar X type is the same... Apparently a volvo rear arm can be used but there are conflicting opinions... They rely on the tolerance of the parts to keep it within spec. I am still of the opinion that either your arm has been damaged or it has hit a kerb...  But you need to get a professional to look as you don't sound like you know what to look for.

Comment: Hmm okay. When I get new tires, I believe it comes with an alignment with the install so I'll have them take a look then. Current set will last another oil change, and then I need more tread for winter.

Any clue what a ballpark cost would be to replace the arms? I've seen some threads where mechanics are just hammering the arms into alignment, but that sounds a little janky to me. We do have a lot of potholes around here so it is possible. I want to say I did have my alignment checked before warranty expired with out of alignment, but the dealership didn't do anything to fix it. Not 100%.